# What is going on with my coffee plant?

Tags: leaves, fertilizer

I have a coffee plant; I don't know the exact variation but I think it's "arabica". I got it as a small plant in a foam coffee cup 10+ years ago. It's currently located on a wall facing an East window. The plant is 10ft away of the window. I water it twice a week: on Mondays and Thursdays.

Recently I started to use a 6-4-6 fertilizer to help it grow. But as always when I use fertilizer it start to loose a bunch of leaves (see attached 2 photos).

Also you can see long branches with leaves only at the end which don't look good (it use to have leaves all the way but they all fallen).

What can I do to help my plant grow? Should I do some cuts?

The plant:

[image: Coffee plant]

Dead leaves (both sides):

[image: Dead leaves]
[image: Dead leaves (reverse)]

Comment: If your coffee plant always reacts negatively to additional fertilizer than why do you keep trying to fertilize it? Leave it be.

Comment: @Rob Yeah I know in the past I used 20-20-20 but I used this one based on plant care that I found on the Web. I'm not sure it's the fertilizer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast forward 1.5 years later and answer my question (since I did not get one back then).

This is my coffee plant now:
[image: Thriving coffee plant]

As you can see it no longer loose leaves (I think it lost like 2 in the last 4.5 months) and it restarted to grow at a steady rate.

So what did I do?

1. Last spring I repotted it in a much larger pot.
2. I added about 55L of acidic soil (PH 4.0-6.0).
3. The last 5cm or so of the pot was a water reservoir which I pierced so that it now drains the excess water (I added a layer of geotextile fabric between the soil and the "reservoir" to keep the soil going down).

The key is the acidic soil and the size of the pot (at a certain point these plants need a large pot to thrive).